# What is the order of execution of filters used Globally at ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, global, execution

In asp.net mvc 5, If the following custom filters(authorization, exception) added globally, then specify the order of execution

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CPExceptionHandler());
        filters.Add(new LogonAuthorizeAttribute());            
    }
```

I tried to understand the order of execution of filters globally from the link
[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx#Filter%20Order), but unable to grasp information. Kindly help me to clarify regarding this, what is the order of execution of global filters such as Authorization, exception etc.,?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx#Anchor_4) it is written the order of execution of exception filter.

Comment: thanq for ur reply. i asked execution order of different filters such as authroization ,exception, response, action filter which are added global only at global.asax file. For eg. I am not sure that the following order will be followed even exception filter added as first at globally as mentioned in the main question.
(1) authorization filter
(2) action filter
(3) response filter
(4) exception filter
could u please mention , which global filter will fire at first either authorization, exception etc.,?

Answer (score 0):

In MVC the order of Filter Execution will always be

**1. Authorization filters**
 **2. Action filters**
 **3. Response filters**
 **4. Exception filters**

The same is applicable even if it is added Globally.

Below is the implementation of the code in MVC

```
 if (actionDescriptor != null)
            {
                FilterInfo filterInfo = GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
                Action continuation = null;

                BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate = delegate(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object asyncState)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = InvokeAuthenticationFilters(controllerContext,
                            filterInfo.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor);
                        if (authenticationContext.Result != null)
                        {
                            // An authentication filter signaled that we should short-circuit the request. Let all
                            // authentication filters contribute to an action result (to combine authentication
                            // challenges). Then, run this action result.
                            AuthenticationChallengeContext challengeContext =
                                InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(controllerContext,
                                filterInfo.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor, authenticationContext.Result);
                            continuation = () => InvokeActionResult(controllerContext,
                                challengeContext.Result ?? authenticationContext.Result);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = InvokeAuthorizationFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.AuthorizationFilters, actionDescriptor);
                            if (authorizationContext.Result != null)
                            {
                                // An authorization filter signaled that we should short-circuit the request. Let all
                                // authentication filters contribute to an action result (to combine authentication
                                // challenges). Then, run this action result.
                                AuthenticationChallengeContext challengeContext =
                                    InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(controllerContext,
                                    filterInfo.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor, authorizationContext.Result);
                                continuation = () => InvokeActionResult(controllerContext,
                                    challengeContext.Result ?? authorizationContext.Result);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (controllerContext.Controller.ValidateRequest)
                                {
                                    ValidateRequest(controllerContext);
                                }

                                IDictionary<string, object> parameters = GetParameterValues(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
                                IAsyncResult asyncResult = BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.ActionFilters, actionDescriptor, parameters, asyncCallback, asyncState);
                                continuation = () =>
                                {
                                    ActionExecutedContext postActionContext = EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(asyncResult);
                                    // The action succeeded. Let all authentication filters contribute to an action
                                    // result (to combine authentication challenges; some authentication filters need
                                    // to do negotiation even on a successful result). Then, run this action result.
                                    AuthenticationChallengeContext challengeContext =
                                        InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(controllerContext,
                                        filterInfo.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor,
                                        postActionContext.Result);
                                    InvokeActionResultWithFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.ResultFilters,
                                        challengeContext.Result ?? postActionContext.Result);
                                };
                                return asyncResult;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ThreadAbortException)
                    {
                        // This type of exception occurs as a result of Response.Redirect(), but we special-case so that
                        // the filters don't see this as an error.
                        throw;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // something blew up, so execute the exception filters
                        ExceptionContext exceptionContext = InvokeExceptionFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.ExceptionFilters, ex);
                        if (!exceptionContext.ExceptionHandled)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }

                        continuation = () => InvokeActionResult(controllerContext, exceptionContext.Result);
                    }

                    return BeginInvokeAction_MakeSynchronousAsyncResult(asyncCallback, asyncState);
                };
```

It will always executes

```
 InvokeAuthorizationFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.AuthorizationFilters, actionDescriptor);
```

then

```
 InvokeAuthenticationFiltersChallenge(controllerContext,
                                    filterInfo.AuthenticationFilters, actionDescriptor, authorizationContext.Result);
```

then

```
ExceptionContext exceptionContext = InvokeExceptionFilters(controllerContext, filterInfo.ExceptionFilters, ex);
```

Here the Order is required only when you have same type filter multiple times

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply :-)
Good Job.
could you please provide any real time example regarding this.

Comment: When a request comes first the you need to authenticate the user and only when an error occurs you need to fire the ExceptionFilter

Comment: Why not Fire ActionFilter method before Authorization filter?

Comment: Only an authorized user can invoke an Action so that Authorization filter has to work first